# Set same height for aside elements inside the div

Tags: html, css

I have the following code in my project, it has many child elements inside the column. when the text length inside the column changes, both aside elements are getting different height. How to set same height to the aside elements in the div using css?

```
<section class="table">
   <div>
     <aside class="column-one">
        <h4></h4>
     </aside>
     <aside class="column-two blue">
        <h4></h4>              
     </aside>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: its not working in my case.

Comment: I did a test, and the duplicated post answer works in your example: flex does keep the same height for both <aside> elements. 

However we should take in account that the element who has to be "display: flex" is the claseless <div> that is the parent of the two <aside>; adding it to the .table or .column-one/two values would not work, so maybe that was your problem.